# Update SSL cert application gateway Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I'm kind of confused of how to approach this. I have to update a cert in my app gateway but I'm not really sure where I have to do it.

I want to do it through Azure CLI and I have two different commands:

- az network application-gateway ssl-cert update
- az network application-gateway http-listener update

I have around 20 listeners that are using the same cert so I don't know if changing the cert in the app gateway will update the listeners or If I have to update the application gateway and then the listeners one by one.

Also, I would like to update it with the cert that it's in my KeyVault but I think it's not supported yet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `az network application-gateway ssl-cert update` renews a certificate associated with a listener. Changing the cert in the app gateway will not update the listeners. The listener configurations remains.

If you use the cert that are stored in your key vault, Azure will automatically renew certificates that are stored in your key vault.

> Application Gateway currently supports software-validated certificates
> only. Hardware security module (HSM)-validated certificates are not
> supported. After Application Gateway is configured to use Key Vault
> certificates, its instances retrieve the certificate from Key Vault
> and install them locally for TLS termination. The instances also poll
> Key Vault at 24-hour intervals to retrieve a renewed version of the
> certificate, if it exists. If an updated certificate is found, the
> TLS/SSL certificate currently associated with the HTTPS listener is
> automatically rotated.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs

Comment: I'm not sure what "Changing the cert in the app gateway will not update the listeners. The listener configurations remains" means?  I assume if you update the app gateway cert, the listener will also be updated or else what is the point of updating the cert?  Perhaps this means if you update the cert via the azure portal UI, it won't work as expected and you need to update the cert via the az command line or arm template.  I'm asking because I updated the cert via the Azure portal UI and app gateway is still using the old cert.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use Key Vault for storing your certificates.
Once imported from a Key Vault certificate will be in synced with the one in Key Vault so you will only need to update/manage certificates in Key Vault and not in each listener.

Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs) if you want to use certificates from Key Vault in your Application Gateway.

Refer to [this article](https://itgala.xyz/letsencrypt-certificates-automatic-renewal-in-azure-application-gateway/) if you want to use Letsencrypt certificates in Application Gateway and renew them automatically.